# How can i have next js and react app in the same project?

Tags: reactjs, seo, next.js, multilingual

How is it possible to integrate in the same project next js (for multilingual seo) and react app for the admin part of the user ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are building with next.js is actually a React app, what do you really mean? If the one application is next.js based and the other one is create-react-app or something like that, then no, you need to run (or serve) them separately.